# How do I make only one property of a model to be updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My viewmodel has a property called Recipient. That has a Property called MobileNumber

I'm trying this in MVC 2:

```
UpdateModel(viewmodel, new[] { "Recipient_MobileNumber" }); // I  expected this to work
```

I also tried "Recipient.MobileNumber"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UpdateModel(viewmodel.Recipient, new[] { "MobileNumber" });
```

Your problem is your using the string[] includes as view data expressions which would hypothetically hop around the object graph to model bind what you need.

UpdateModel doesn't work that way.  Those strings are simply used as filters over properties.

Comment: I had to add a prefix, but this got me on the right track to this:

UpdateModel(viewmodel.Recipient, "Recipient", new[] { "MobileNumber" });

Comment: Ps. Thanks for the explanation. It all perfect sense once I read your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that I suppose:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id /* id of recipient? */, FormCollection formValues)
{
    var viewmodel = GetViewModel(id);
    viewmodel.Recipient.ModileNumber = formValues["Recipient.MobileNumber"];
}
```